# How to make nested data into linear data using jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

How can I convert this nested data to linear format data as mentioned below using jolt. Need to create separate entry for all the nested data. every record should have 5 data in it practice_loc,prac_num,topId,S1 and S2.
Need to create separate entry for all the nested data. every record should have 5 data in it practice_loc,prac_num,topId,S1 and S2.
**InPut data**

```
[
 {
    "practice_loc": 120,
    "prac_num": 234,
    "topId": "t1",
    "subList": [
      {
        "S1": "A1",
        "S2": "B1"
      },
      {
        "S1": "A2"
      }
    ]
  },
 {
    "practice_loc": 334,
    "prac_num": 233,
    "topId": "plumcherry",
    "subList": [
      {
        "S1": "A3"
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "practice_loc": 987,
    "prac_num": 232,
    "topId": "artica",
    "subList": [
      {
        "S1": "A5",
        "S2": "B7"
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "practice_loc": 987,
    "prac_num": 232,
    "topId": "rose",
    "subList": [
      {
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[
{
    "practice_loc": 120,
    "prac_num": 234,
    "topId": "t1",
    "S1": "A1",
    "S2": "B1"
  },
  {
    "practice_loc": 120,
    "prac_num": 234,
    "topId": "t1",
    "S1": "A2",
    "S2":""
 },
{
    "practice_loc": 334,
    "prac_num": 233,
    "topId": "plumcherry",
    "S1": "A3",
    "S2":""    
},
{
    "practice_loc": 987,
    "prac_num": 232,
    "topId": "artica",
    "S1": "A5",
    "S2": "B7"
  },
{
"practice_loc": 987,
    "prac_num": 232,
    "topId": "rose",
     "S1": "",
    "S2":""
}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bring the result dynamically as

```json
[
  { // group elements by upper level objects wrapper nodes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "subList": {
          "*": {
            "@2|@": "&3_&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the wrappers
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[#3].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the extra generated array, namely "subList"
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "subList": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hello Barbaros, I have changed my question, can you please update answer, initially I was taking all data within [ ] brackets but now I'll get data in splitted files so no [ ] brackets and I have to write one jolt whic can handle all possibilities of input data

Comment: Hello @dracile . It would be better to revert this one to the previous case, and ask a new one as this is already a completed(answered) question.

Comment: Hi Ozhan, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76429897/how-to-convert-nested-data-into-linear-data-using-jolt  this is the new question , I am reverting this one